# Python dataframe unexpected display error using loc

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating an additional column "Total_Count" to store the cumulative count record by Site and Count_Record column information. My coding is almost done for total cumulative count. However, the Total_Count column is shift for a specific Card as below. Could someone help with code modification, thank you!

**Expected Output:**

[image]

**Current Output:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['site', 'card', 'date', 'count_record'],
      data=[['A', 'C1', '12-Oct', 5], 
            ['A', 'C1', '13-Oct', 10], 
            ['A', 'C1', '14-Oct', 18],
            ['A', 'C1', '15-Oct', 21], 
            ['A', 'C1', '16-Oct', 29],
            ['B', 'C2', '12-Oct', 11],
            ['A', 'C2', '13-Oct', 2],
            ['A', 'C2', '14-Oct', 7],
            ['A', 'C2', '15-Oct', 13],
            ['B', 'C2', '16-Oct', 4]])

df_append_temp=[]

total = 0
preCard = ''
preSite = ''
preCount = 0

for pc in df1['card'].unique():
    df2 = df1[df1['card'] == pc].sort_values(['date'])

    total = 0

    for i in range(0, len(df2)):
        site = df2.iloc[i]['site']
        count = df2.iloc[i]['count_record']
    
        if site == preSite:
            total += (count - preCount)
        else:
            total += count
    
        preCount = count
        preSite = site

        df2.loc[i, 'Total_Count'] = total #something wrong using loc here
    
    df_append_temp.append(df2)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(df_append_temp), columns=df2.columns)
df3
```

Comment: `i` is an integer location. `loc` is label based location. You should use `iloc` as above. `df2.loc[i, df2.columns.get_loc('Total_Count')] = total`. You'd need to initialize the `Total_Count` column first though with that approach.

Comment: label based location doesn't work here since you subset `df1[df1['card'] == pc]` you're not guaranteed to get a contiguous default range index 0-length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the current implementation we can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html) to create our `df2` which allows us to [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) a function to each grouped DataFrame to create the new column. This should offer similar performance as the current implementation but produce correctly aligned Series:

```
def calc_total_count(df2: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    total = 0
    pre_count = 0
    pre_site = ''
    lst = []
    for c, s in zip(df2['count_record'], df2['site']):
        if s == pre_site:
            total += (c - pre_count)
        else:
            total += c

        pre_count = c
        pre_site = s
        lst.append(total)
    return pd.Series(lst, index=df2.index, name='Total_Count')


df3 = pd.concat([
    df1,
    df1.sort_values('date').groupby('card').apply(calc_total_count).droplevel(0)
], axis=1)
```

Alternatively we can use `groupby`, then within groups [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to get the previous `site`, and `count_record`. Then use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to conditionally determine each row's value and [`ndarray.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.cumsum.html) to calculate the cumulative total of the resulting values:

```
def calc_total_count(df2: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.Series(
        np.where(df2['site'] == df2['site'].shift(),
                 df2['count_record'] - df2['count_record'].shift(fill_value=0),
                 df2['count_record']).cumsum(),
        index=df2.index,
        name='Total_Count'
    )


df3 = pd.concat([
    df1,
    df1.sort_values('date').groupby('card').apply(calc_total_count).droplevel(0)
], axis=1)
```

Either approach produces `df3`:

```
  site card    date  count_record  Total_Count
0    A   C1  12-Oct             5            5
1    A   C1  13-Oct            10           10
2    A   C1  14-Oct            18           18
3    A   C1  15-Oct            21           21
4    A   C1  16-Oct            29           29
5    B   C2  12-Oct            11           11
6    A   C2  13-Oct             2           13
7    A   C2  14-Oct             7           18
8    A   C2  15-Oct            13           24
9    B   C2  16-Oct             4           28
```

---

Setup and imports:

```
import numpy as np  # only needed if using np.where
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['site', 'card', 'date', 'count_record'],
                   data=[['A', 'C1', '12-Oct', 5],
                         ['A', 'C1', '13-Oct', 10],
                         ['A', 'C1', '14-Oct', 18],
                         ['A', 'C1', '15-Oct', 21],
                         ['A', 'C1', '16-Oct', 29],
                         ['B', 'C2', '12-Oct', 11],
                         ['A', 'C2', '13-Oct', 2],
                         ['A', 'C2', '14-Oct', 7],
                         ['A', 'C2', '15-Oct', 13],
                         ['B', 'C2', '16-Oct', 4]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Henry Ecker ! Your code is working perfectly, as well as solved my trouble of cumulative summation. You saved me a lot of time.